# How do I convert an array of integers to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I would like to convert and array in this format

```
var values = [1,2,3];
```

To an array in this format

```
var data = [ 
  {x: 0, value: 1},
  {x: 1, value: 2},
  {x: 2, value: 3}
];
```

Comment: typo    var data = [ 
      {x: 0, value: 1},
      {x: 1, value: 2},
      {x: 2, value: 3}
    ];

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could simply use the `Array.prototype.map` method:

```
var data = values.map(function(el, i) {
   return {
     x: i,
     value: el
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will do the trick:

```
var values = [1,2,3];
var _dict = [];

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   _dict.push( {x: i, value: values[i]} );
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjLc9ctu/3)

Comment: Do not use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) on arrays. This is like the model case for that argument.

Comment: @Oka  Thanks. Didn't knew that. Is the modified code good enough?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer has several problems. 1. OP wants to create an array of objects not an object. 2. You shouldn't use the `for ... in` loop for iterating through arrays. 3. The `x` and  `y` should be separate properties. Define the `_dict` as an array, iterate properly and then use the `Array.prototype.push` method for pushing an object into the array.

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks for commenting. You didn't downvote but I did upvote your answer. I am new to javascript as well that's why the answer is mediocre :)

Comment: Thanks for that :). Yes, but you forgot to define the `_dict` variable as an array. `var _dict = [];`

Comment: @Vohuman Oops. I actually modified in the JSFiddle but forgot to change here. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

A basic option would be:

```
var values = [1,2,3]; 

var newValues = [];
for(var i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
    newValues.push( {x: i, values: values[i]} );
}
```